# What's difference in ::ModuleName::ClassName and ModuleName::ClassName

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

In ruby, I'm starting to see a pretty normal practice including modules and mixins referenced as ::ModuleName::ClassName, where in the past it was pretty much just ModuleName::ClassName.

What I'd like to get here is a decent understanding of why this practice is being seen more lately and what it does differently.

What's the difference?

What's the benefit (if the prior doesn't answer this)?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you put the `::` in the beginning you are referring to the global namespace, if you don't you are referring to your current namespace.

Usually if you don't have a class/module with the same name inside your class/module you would not need to use the `::` in the beginning.

```
class Customer

  def to_s
    "Customer global"
  end

end


class Order

  class Customer
    def to_s
      "Customer within order"
    end
  end


  def initialize
    puts Customer.new
    puts ::Customer.new
  end


end

Order.new
```

will print out

```
Customer within order
Customer global
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `::ModuleName::ClassName` you're saying:

> I want you to look for `::ModuleName::ClassName` at the root namespace, ignoring if this code is found inside another module. So, it will always look for a class that's named as `::ModuleName::ClassName` and nothing else

When you say it like this `ModuleName::ClassName`, you're saying:

> I want you to look for `ModuleName::ClassName` but looking at the current scope first and then at the other scopes. So, if you have a module called MyModule and this my module references `ModuleName::ClassName` then first try to find `MyModule::ModuleName::ClassName` then try to resolve `::ModuleName::ClassName`.

When I'm defining code like this I almost always use ::ModuleName::ClassName to avoid any naming conflicts.

Comment: Interesting, so I guess that you can use it either way. Use :: to verify you don't have naming issues, and use nothing if there is a situation that will cause a naming conflict?  Or would you at that point, rename a class?

Comment: That depends, sometimes you have a plugin or gem with the same name as your class (i've seen this happen myself with the acts_as_taggable gem) and I ended up renaming my model. Nowadays I always use :: when using namespaced classes and I always define my classes with **class SomeModule::SomeClass; end** instead of **module SomeModule; class SomeClass; end ; end**. In the end, it becomes much simpler to search for a class by it's full name.